# Modifying fields with multiIf

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to modify some shortened data to their full forms. For that I'm using the below query.

```
WITH (SELECT DISTINCT platform FROM myTable) AS platform1
SELECT 
    multiIf(platform1 = "A", "ANDROID",
        platform1 = "W", "WINDOWS",
        platform1 = "I", "iOS"
    ) AS platform2
```

But clikhouse is throwing an error:

```
DB::Exception: Scalar subquery returned more than one row.
```

How to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT multiIf(
        platform1 = 'A', 'ANDROID',
        platform1 = 'W', 'WINDOWS',
        platform1 = 'I', 'iOS',
        'Unknown') AS platform2 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT platform FROM myTable)
```

or

```sql
SELECT CASE platform1
         WHEN 'A' THEN 'ANDROID'
         WHEN 'W' THEN 'WINDOWS'
         WHEN 'I' THEN 'iOS'
         ELSE 'Unknown'
       END AS platform2 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT platform FROM myTable)
```

Comment: surprisingly the 1st one worked. I tired the same before just without the else statement. Thanks.